# Format a numbered list in google docs into a table template?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs, export

I have a list with a url, an emoji (of a set of 3), and a name in a numbered list.

Taking a list like this:

> 1. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=38122061  D. onohoe
> 2. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=38076530  H. Trp
> 3. 33411748                                       Drew P.
> 4. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=29083367  J. Abo
> 5. 15614660                                       Ben Breen

How could I fit this into a table?
Keeping the numbers as variables. Swapping emojis for status. Adding a notes column. The broken urls are reflective of the list because they can be googled for the correct url, but were added to meet the 8 url submission limit on StackExchange.

| # | URL | Status | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=38122061|](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=38122061%7C) In Progress | D. Onohoe |  |
| 2 | [https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=38076530|](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=38076530%7C) Finished | H. Trp |  |
| 3 | [https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=33411748|](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=33411748%7C) Reviewed | Drew P. |  |
| 4 | [https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=29083367|](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=29083367%7C) Pending | J. Abo |  |
| 5 | [https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15614660|](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15614660%7C) Submitted | Ben Breen |  |

Highlighting and selecting table does not work and pasting the information into a table only fills the first cell. For processing and then eventual migration or referencing into google sheets.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  What do you mean numbers as variables?  What is a variable in Google Docs? Is this a Docs to Docs question or a Docs to Sheets?  Are you basically asking how to copy the list of links into rows of a table?

Answer (score 0):

You can paste your list from Docs into Google Sheets and  each list item will be treated as a single row.

Assuming you paste the list in Column `A`, the formula below will:

1. Extract the 8 digit IDs,
2. Build URLs from the IDs,
3. Recreate the list numbering.

```
=LET(rng,TOCOL(A:A,1),
   { SEQUENCE(ROWS(rng)),
     ARRAYFORMULA(
       "https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id="&
       REGEXEXTRACT(rng,"\d{8}"))} )
```

**Formula in `B1`**
[image]

## Emojis with Meaning

If the emojis map into the status messages, you can use HLOOKUP to return it.

The lookup values can be an array included in the formula or stored in a referenced range.

#### HLOOKUP Formula

- Example where lookup values are an array in the formula:

```
=HLOOKUP(      
   REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\d{8}.?(.?)"),
   {"", "", "";
    "Finished", "In Progress", "Reviewed"},
   2,0)
```

Combining the emoji mapping HLOOKUP formula with the original formula will add a third column that displays the status:

```
=LET(rng,TOCOL(A:A,1),
   { SEQUENCE(ROWS(rng)),
     ARRAYFORMULA(
      { "https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id="&
           REGEXEXTRACT(rng,"\d{8}"), 
        HLOOKUP(
          REGEXEXTRACT(rng,"\d{8}.?(.?)"),
          {"", "", "";
           "Finished", "In Progress", "Reviewed"},
          2,0)})})
```